# How to bind url encoded parameters in GET endpoint?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have the following controller:

```
...
@GetMapping("/developers")
ResponseEntity<Page<DeveloperDTO>> getDevelopersData(@ModelAttribute DevelopersFilterDTO 
filter){...}
...
```

for simplicity i omitted code around the controller.
In my DTO i have the following property:

```
private Optional<String> fioPart;
```

I want to pass fioPart in **URL encoded params**.

How to edit controller so that it accepts and binds url encoded parameters from the request?